# Adding custom objects to list<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have a problem, I cannot add custom objects to my List. However, if I add some predefined objects (strings, integers..) my code works just fine.
This is my class which is always returned on all ajax calls to this controller, it contains boolean Status and List of objects.

```
    public class returnData
    {
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public List<object> data { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the class for the object I want to add to this list:

```
public class file
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The code where I use this:

```
returnData data = new returnData();
...
DriveFile file = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DriveFile>(Json);

file f = new file();
if (file.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
{
    f.Type = "folder";
    f.ID = file.id;
    f.Name = file.title;
    data.data.Add(f);
}
```

The error I get has no useful info, as this code compiles and the error is in Chrome Console log when the ajax is executed.

[Image of google chrome console](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B12D7SjI9fgqQkQzazE1SEVhV1U/edit?usp=sharing)

However, when I use this line of code

```
data.data.add("some string");
```

my function will work flawlessly and return Object which contains boolean Status and List of objects (strings, integers..)

So back to my question, how do I add my objects to this list?

EDIT: There are no server side errors, the code compiles and runs just fine, so this probably is some jquery/ajax error.

This is the ajax code for my debugger:

```
86    $.ajax({
87  url: $('#url').val(),
88  type: $('#type option:selected').val(),
89  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
90  dataType: "json",
91  data: $('#data').val(),
92  success: function (result){
93  console.log(result)
94  },
95  error: function (err){
96  console.log(err)
97  }                   
98    });
```

Here is the complete method, but the method seems to be OK, it is the ajax or something to do with jquery I guess.

```
[OperationContract]
    public returnData listChildren(string folderId)
    {
        returnData data = new returnData();
        List<object> myList= new List<object>();

        bool status = true;
        try
        {
            string Json = Response("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + folderId + "/children", "GET");
//get the children list
            if (!Json.Contains("error"))
            {
                DriveChildlist list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DriveChildlist>(Json);
                foreach (DriveChildren child in list.items)
                {
                    string uriString = child.childLink;
//get the info for each child in the list
                    Json = Response(uriString, "GET");
                    if (!Json.Contains("error"))
                    {
                        DriveFile file = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DriveFile>(Json);
                        file f = new file();
                        if (file.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
                        {
                            f.Type = "folder";
                            f.ID = file.id;
                            f.Name = file.title;
                            data.data.Add(f);

                        }
                        else if (file.mimeType == "application/myMimeType")
                        {
                            f.Type = "file";
                            f.ID = file.id;
                            f.Name = file.title;
                            data.data.Add(f);

                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = false;
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                status = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        data.status = status;
        if (!status)
        {

            data.data = null;
//data.data is null if status is false
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error with no useful info that you're getting?

Comment: This is the link to the picture, nothing useful
[link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B12D7SjI9fgqQkQzazE1SEVhV1U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is on the client side,  any errors on the server side? Also, if after `returnData data = new returnData();` you add `data.data = new list<object>;` does it make any difference?

Comment: I have no errors on server side, the code compiles and runs just fine, it even sets the data.data list, however, I receive that error on the client side. 
data.data=new List<object> does not affect the results.

Comment: what's happening after the `data.data.add(...)` method is called?  let's see the whole method

Comment: specifically, show us what you do with the `returnData` object `data`

Answer (score 0):

As written your C# code won't work but will compile.  It will throw an error when the ajax is called and you may never see the error message (depending on how your system is setup).

Here is correct code (given your snippet)

```
returnData data = new returnData();
data.data = new List<object>();
// rest of your code.
```

Comment: Not working, I keep getting the same error when I try to put objects in it. Since it is working with, for example strings, perhaps the error is in my file class?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the Newtonsoft.Json. I have serialized the object using this code:

```
string jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

and then I returned the serialized string instead of object. Looks like visual studio development center failed to serialize my object, even after adding [Serializable()] to my class. Any info on that?